# Correct way to write rspec/capybara test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I'm trying to implement tests the correct way. I'm currently working on having users sign up. I would like the first user to sign up to be an admin and then every user after that to be a regular user.

I'm currently thinking I need to write my test as a feature but I'm wondering if this should actually be a model test.

My current code is right here

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do
    subject { page }

    describe "Sign up page" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        it { should have_button('Create!') }
    end

    describe "Creating an account" do
        before { visit signup_path }
        let(:submit) { "Create!" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create the user account" do
            expect { click_button "Create!"}.not_to change(User, :count)
        end

        describe "it should display errors" do
            before { click_button submit }

            it { should have_content('Failed signup') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password", with: "password"
            fill_in "Confirm Password", with: "password"
        end

        it "should create the user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        # User sign in not implemented at this point
        describe "the first user" do
            User.all.count.should == 0
            click_button submit
            User.all.count.should == 1
            @firstUser = User.first
            @firstUser.is_admin?.should == true

            describe "the second user" do
                before do
                    visit signup_path
                    fill_in "Name", with: "Example User2"
                    fill_in "Email", with: "user2@example.com"
                    fill_in "Password", with: "password"
                    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: "password"
                end

                click_button submit
                @secondUser = User.all.last
                @secondUser.is_admin?.should == false
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

I'm mostly concerned with the "with valid information" part and would like to clean that up so it fits in with rspec/capybara correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this great [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) by michael hartl , he use Rspec in this tutorial you can learn from it :)
i am a beginner too and i started with it :D

Comment: I just finished his tutorial. I've been following his code on Github and applying what I learned but this is something that I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: check this screencast [Ruby for Newbies: Testing with Rspec](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec/) and also a course from the beginning in Rspec by Code School [Testing with RSpec](http://codeschool.com/courses/testing-with-rspec)